# Split string to parameters and values

Tags: regex, vb.net

I know for basic split string manipulation but as a VB.NET beginner I would like to know if here exists some handy way to split strings with parameters (tokens).
String may be different in size and contents but always with same schema "[parameter]->value".
Like this:

```
[name] John [year]   1990 [gender]M[state] Washington[married] No[employed] No
```

How to parse this, syntacticly bad written string to get parameter->value pairs?

EDIT: An example of code, regex or similar please.

Comment: You should try using regular expressions.

Comment: Hi Marc, can you provide some link with example on similar situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression:

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex( _
    "\[         # Match an opening bracket"                         & chr(10) & _
    "(?<name>   # Match and capture into group ""name"":"           & chr(10) & _
    " [^[\]]*   # any number of characters except brackets"         & chr(10) & _
    ")          # End of capturing group"                           & chr(10) & _
    "\]         # Match a closing bracket"                          & chr(10) & _
    "\s*        # Match optional whitespace"                        & chr(10) & _
    "(?<value>  # Match and capture into group ""value"":"          & chr(10) & _
    " [^[\]]*?  # any number of characters except brackets"         & chr(10) & _
    ")          # End of capturing group"                           & chr(10) & _
    "(?=        # Assert that we end this match either when"        & chr(10) & _
    " \s*\[     # optional whitespace and an opening bracket"       & chr(10) & _
    "|          # or"                                               & chr(10) & _
    " \s*$      # whitespace and the end of the string"             & chr(10) & _
    ")          # are present after the current position", _
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
Dim MatchResults As Match = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString)
While MatchResults.Success
    parameter = MatchResults.Groups("name").Value
    value = MatchResults.Groups("value").Value
    ' do something with the parameter/value pairs
    MatchResults = MatchResults.NextMatch()
End While
```

Comment: I get your code working but I don't know to write expression so don't get any result. I write this... im RegexObj As New Regex(("\[\]"), RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace) to get parameter names but don't go that way.

Comment: Uh, I'm not quite following. The regex provided in my answer already contains everything to match parameters and values.

Comment: Sorry Tim. You only forget to put an underslash at end of line 1 and line 15 and my IDE shows errors. Amazing example!!! Works just as expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user973238: Thanks for the feedback. I used RegexBuddy to construct a VB.NET code snippet from my regex, and it didn't provide the underscores. I will inform the developer about that error.